# How to add a sudo password to a delegated host

Tags: ansible

How do you add a sudo password to a delegated host?

eg.

```
hosts: host1

  - name: Some remote command
    command: sudo some command
    register: result
    delegate_to: host2
    become: yes
```

I get "Incorrect sudo password" because I assume it is using the sudo pass for host1. Is there a way to make it use a different password?

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while - but I was struggling with this as well and managed to solve it so here is a summarized answer:

As pointed out correctly  the issue is that the `ansible_become_password` variable is set to to your original host (`host1`) when running the delegated task on `host2`.

**Option 1: Add become password to inventory and delegate facts**

One option to solve this is to specify the become password for `host2` in your inventory, and secure it using ansible vault (as they have done here: [How to specify become password for tasks delegated to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60427192/how-to-specify-become-password-for-tasks-delegated-to-localhost)). Then you should be able to trigger using the correct sudo pw with `delegate_facts` as they did here [Ansible delegate_to "Incorrect sudo password"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948554/ansible-delegate-to-incorrect-sudo-password).

**Option 2: Prompt and overwrite pass manually**

If you prefer to get prompted for the second sudo password instead, you can do this by using a [vars_promt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html) to specify the second sudo pw during runtime:

```
- hosts: host1

  vars_prompt:
    - name: custom_become_pass
      prompt: enter the custom become password for host2
      private: yes

  tasks:
    ...
```

Then you can just replace the variable `ansible_become_password` before running your delegated tasks and it will use the correct sudo password:

```
tasks:
 - name: do stuff on host1
     ...

 - name: set custom become
   set_fact:
     ansible_become_password: '{{ custom_become_pass }}'

 - name: perform delegated task
    command: sudo some command
    register: result
    delegate_to: host2
    become: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use **ansible_become_password** variable directly inside the task's var section. 
[Ansible doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#connection-variables)

Comment: Do you know how to set this only for host2? I can set this variable which will change the sudo password for host1

Comment: @lajmode you can set this variable directly inside the inventory file.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-one-machine-host-variables